# Positioning constraints not having any effect

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to code the label in the `viewDidLoad` function. The label is showing up but the code I am using now is not affecting the positioning. I am trying to code everything in the `viewDidLoad` function. You can see the screenshot below.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let backbutton = UILabel()
    backbutton.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
    backbutton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    backbutton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
    backbutton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
    backbutton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backbutton.centerXAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
    backbutton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backbutton.centerYAnchor, constant: 300).isActive = true
    view.addSubview(backbutton)
}
```

[image]

Comment: You are trying to constraint the button to its own centre.  You want `backbutton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true` and the similar thing for the Y center

Comment: @Paulw11 That does not work.

Comment: @Paulw11 a runtime error occurs.

Comment: You need to add the button to its superview before you can create constraints that reference the superview

Comment: before applying any constraint first add the `backbutton` as subview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can align the `label` into the `center` of the `view`,

```
let backbutton = UILabel()
view.addSubview(backbutton)

backbutton.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
backbutton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
backbutton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
backbutton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
backbutton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
backbutton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

When you are setting `constraints` programmatically, make sure you add the `view` into the `super/parent` `view` before applying `constraints`. Secondly in the below lines, you are telling the `backButton` label to align its center to itself (i.e, **backbutton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backbutton.centerXAnchor**).

```
backbutton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backbutton.centerXAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
backbutton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backbutton.centerYAnchor, constant: 300).isActive = true
```

As you want to align it center `vertically` and `horizontally` to its `parent view` so you should set the `center` `constraints` equal to `parent view` as below,

```
backbutton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
backbutton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this!!

```
 self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: OP added constraint in `viewDidLoad`, after `viewDidLoad` constraint already update once.

Comment: still that constraint not getting updated might view is not settled down. so explicitly called it.

Comment: My guess is that OP added constraint before adding the subview.

Answer (score 0):

Try using CGRect instead:

```
            let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
            let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
            let xPostion:CGFloat = screenWidth - 150 //150 is half of view's width
            let yPostion:CGFloat = screenHeight - 150 //150 is half of view's height
            let buttonWidth:CGFloat = 300
            let buttonHeight:CGFloat = 300
            backbutton.frame = CGRect(x:xPostion, y:yPostion, width:buttonWidth, height:buttonHeight)
```

instead of screen width/height you can also try to get the width of your super view using:

```
  self.view.frame.width 
  self.view.frame.height
```